# How to retrieve all images from website (not just from index.html) using wget

Tags: html, wget

I'm a bit confused because I've googled for like an hour and I still did not find a solution to this.

I'm trying to download all the images from a website using wget :

```
wget -nd -r --level=inf -P Desktop -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png http://site/path
```

But it only downloads the images that are present in `index.html` , the recursion does not happen...

If I download the whole website without using the patterns `-A..` , I get to see all the images but I don't need the rest of the documents , just the pictures.

Is there any solution to this ?

Thank you.